# SQL Index Spool(eager spool) Speed up Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I wrote a while back to help generate an XML file that would be used to share data with external resources. Basically the end user dumps data inside a table called DataSharing and then when we execute the Query it will return back an XML document with the required fields specified inside DataSharing. Now this procedure does work well however it is extremely slow. When I run it via SSMS and set 'show actual execution plan', 94% of the query is spent on index spool (eager spool). Upon researching it looks like I should probably rework the query to perform better.

Since the columns of the data I never know what they are I had to do unique pivot in order to generate my data.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HPSDDataSharing]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fileName varchar(MAX), @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(MAX), @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @listStr =
      COALESCE(@listStr +',' ,'') + '[' +  [ColumnName] + ']'
  FROM [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[DataSharing]
  WHERE FileName = @fileName
  DECLARE @Result XML
  SET @sqlCommand = 'Select * From ( SELECT 
      [DatapointDate]
      ,dp.ColumnName
      ,[DataPointValue]
    FROM [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[vw_DataCollection] DC
  JOIN [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[Datasharing] dp
  ON DC.DataPointID = DP.DatapointID
  WHERE 
  [DatapointDate] >= ''' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @StartDate) + '''
  and [DatapointDate] < ''' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @EndDate) + '''
  and  dc.DataPointID in (SELECT [DatapointID] FROM [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[DataSharing] Where FileName = ''' + @fileName + ''')
  ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(DataPointValue)
        FOR ColumnName IN ('+ @listStr +')
    ) as pvt
    ORDER BY DatapointDate
    FOR XML Path(''' + 'DataRow' + '''), ROOT;'

    Print @sqlCommand

    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

END



GO
```

The fully executed query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT [datapointdate], 
               dp.columnname, 
               [datapointvalue] 
        FROM   [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[vw_datacollection] DC 
               JOIN [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing] dp 
                 ON DC.datapointid = DP.datapointid 
        WHERE  [datapointdate] >= 'Jul 15 2013 12:00AM' 
               AND [datapointdate] < 'Jul 22 2013 12:00AM' 
               AND dc.datapointid IN (SELECT [datapointid] 
                                      FROM   [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing] 
                                      WHERE  filename = 'fdrD3')) AS source 
       PIVOT ( Sum(datapointvalue) 
             FOR columnname IN ([fdrD3_kWh_A], 
                                [fdrD3_kWh_B], 
                                [fdrD3_kWh_C], 
                                [fdrD3_kWh], 
                                [fdrD3_I_A], 
                                [fdrD3_I_B], 
                                [fdrD3_I_C], 
                                [fdrD3_I_N], 
                                [fdrD3_V_A], 
                                [fdrD3_V_B], 
                                [fdrD3_V_C], 
                                [fdrD3_V_A-B], 
                                [fdrD3_V_B-C], 
                                [fdrD3_kV_C-A], 
                                [fdrD3_kW], 
                                [fdrD3_kVA], 
                                [fdrD3_kVAr], 
                                [fdrD3_kW_A], 
                                [fdrD3_kW_B], 
                                [fdrD3_kW_C], 
                                [fdrD3_kVA_A], 
                                [fdrD3_kVA_B], 
                                [fdrD3_kVA_C], 
                                [fdrD3_kVAr_A], 
                                [fdrD3_kVAr_B], 
                                [fdrD3_kVAr_C], 
                                [fdrD3_F], 
                                [fdrD3_Iang_A], 
                                [fdrD3_Iang_B], 
                                [fdrD3_Iang_C], 
                                [fdrD3_Iang_N], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_A], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_B], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_C], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_A-B], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_B-C], 
                                [fdrD3_Vang_C-A], 
                                [fdrD3_PF_A], 
                                [fdrD3_PF_B], 
                                [fdrD3_PF_C], 
                                [fdrD3_PF], 
                                [fdrD3_Pst_V_A], 
                                [fdrD3_Pst_V_B], 
                                [fdrD3_Pst_V_C], 
                                [fdrD3_Plt_V_A], 
                                [fdrD3_Plt_V_B], 
                                [fdrD3_Plt_V_C], 
                                [fdrD3_Vdev_A], 
                                [fdrD3_Vdev_B], 
                                [fdrD3_Vdev_C], 
                                [fdrD3_Fdev], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_I_A], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_I_B], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_I_C], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_I_N], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_V_A], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_V_B], 
                                [fdrD3_THD_V_C]) ) AS pvt 
ORDER  BY datapointdate 
FOR xml path('DataRow'), root;
```

So the current procedure currently takes 35-65 seconds to run. I really need to see about speeding this procedure up as I am dealing with timeouts. If anyone can help me out in what I can do to help speed this up and get rid of so much time being spent on Index Spool(eager spool) I would appreciate it.

Edit 1:

I added a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1507c/2/0) so hopefully this helps.

Comment: Well one minor thing is not convert the start and end dates to a string and back to a date.

Comment: Without a good indication on how said tables look like, what indexes they have (or don't have), what volumes they are, if there are foreign-key relations etc ... there is very little people can suggest... If possible, go to SQLFiddle, make sure to build all the related tables and their indexes etc. and then copy the code here, that way there is at least a chance you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: @Hogan I thought about that. But when I excute with out the Pivot it only takes about 6 seconds to execute which is pretty good since we have 547k rows of data.

Comment: @kevinc try my query below in answer and let me know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your pivot unwound -- see if this runs any faster (I bet it will mostly because of the optimization of the CTE), if it does then you can re-write your generator to create a query that looks like this:

```
WITH datelist
(
   SELECT datapointid, filename, datapointvalue
   FROM [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing]
   WHERE  datapointdate >= @StartDate AND datapointdate < @EndDate AND filename = @filename
)
SELECT
  SUM( j1.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kWh_A
  SUM( j2.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kWh_B 
  SUM( j3.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kWh_C 
  SUM( j4.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kWh 
  SUM( j5.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_I_A 
  SUM( j6.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_I_B 
  SUM( j7.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_I_C 
  SUM( j8.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_I_N 
  SUM( j9.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_V_A 
  SUM(j10.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_V_B 
  SUM(j12.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_V_C 
  SUM(j13.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_V_A_B 
  SUM(j14.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_V_B_C 
  SUM(j15.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kV_C_A 
  SUM(j16.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kW 
  SUM(j17.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVA 
  SUM(j18.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVAr 
  SUM(j19.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kW_A 
  SUM(j20.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kW_B 
  SUM(j21.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kW_C 
  SUM(j22.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVA_A 
  SUM(j23.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVA_B 
  SUM(j24.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVA_C 
  SUM(j25.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVAr_A 
  SUM(j26.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVAr_B 
  SUM(j27.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_kVAr_C 
  SUM(j28.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_F 
  SUM(j29.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Iang_A 
  SUM(j20.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Iang_B 
  SUM(j31.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Iang_C 
  SUM(j32.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Iang_N 
  SUM(j33.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_A 
  SUM(j34.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_B 
  SUM(j35.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_C 
  SUM(j36.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_A_B 
  SUM(j37.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_B_C 
  SUM(j38.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vang_C_A 
  SUM(j39.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_PF_A 
  SUM(j40.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_PF_B 
  SUM(j41.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_PF_C 
  SUM(j42.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_PF 
  SUM(j43.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Pst_V_A 
  SUM(j44.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Pst_V_B 
  SUM(j45.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Pst_V_C 
  SUM(j46.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Plt_V_A 
  SUM(j47.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Plt_V_B 
  SUM(j48.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Plt_V_C 
  SUM(j49.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vdev_A 
  SUM(j50.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vdev_B 
  SUM(j51.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Vdev_C 
  SUM(j52.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_Fdev 
  SUM(j53.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_I_A 
  SUM(j54.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_I_B 
  SUM(j55.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_I_C 
  SUM(j56.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_I_N 
  SUM(j57.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_V_A 
  SUM(j58.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_V_B 
  SUM(j59.datepointvalue) as sum_fdrD3_THD_V_C
FROM   [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[vw_datacollection] DC 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j1 ON DC.datapointid =  j1.datapointid AND  j1.columnname = 'fdrD3_kWh_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j2 ON DC.datapointid =  j2.datapointid AND  j2.columnname = 'fdrD3_kWh_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j3 ON DC.datapointid =  j3.datapointid AND  j3.columnname = 'fdrD3_kWh_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j4 ON DC.datapointid =  j4.datapointid AND  j4.columnname = 'fdrD3_kWh' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j5 ON DC.datapointid =  j5.datapointid AND  j5.columnname = 'fdrD3_I_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j6 ON DC.datapointid =  j6.datapointid AND  j6.columnname = 'fdrD3_I_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j7 ON DC.datapointid =  j7.datapointid AND  j7.columnname = 'fdrD3_I_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j8 ON DC.datapointid =  j8.datapointid AND  j8.columnname = 'fdrD3_I_N' 
LEFT JOIN datelist  j9 ON DC.datapointid =  j9.datapointid AND  j9.columnname = 'fdrD3_V_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j10 ON DC.datapointid = j10.datapointid AND j10.columnname = 'fdrD3_V_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j12 ON DC.datapointid = j12.datapointid AND j12.columnname = 'fdrD3_V_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j13 ON DC.datapointid = j13.datapointid AND j13.columnname = 'fdrD3_V_A-B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j14 ON DC.datapointid = j14.datapointid AND j14.columnname = 'fdrD3_V_B-C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j15 ON DC.datapointid = j15.datapointid AND j15.columnname = 'fdrD3_kV_C-A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j16 ON DC.datapointid = j16.datapointid AND j16.columnname = 'fdrD3_kW' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j17 ON DC.datapointid = j17.datapointid AND j17.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVA' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j18 ON DC.datapointid = j18.datapointid AND j18.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVAr' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j19 ON DC.datapointid = j19.datapointid AND j19.columnname = 'fdrD3_kW_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j20 ON DC.datapointid = j20.datapointid AND j20.columnname = 'fdrD3_kW_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j21 ON DC.datapointid = j21.datapointid AND j21.columnname = 'fdrD3_kW_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j22 ON DC.datapointid = j22.datapointid AND j22.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVA_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j23 ON DC.datapointid = j23.datapointid AND j23.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVA_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j24 ON DC.datapointid = j24.datapointid AND j24.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVA_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j25 ON DC.datapointid = j25.datapointid AND j25.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVAr_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j26 ON DC.datapointid = j26.datapointid AND j26.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVAr_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j27 ON DC.datapointid = j27.datapointid AND j27.columnname = 'fdrD3_kVAr_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j28 ON DC.datapointid = j28.datapointid AND j28.columnname = 'fdrD3_F' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j29 ON DC.datapointid = j29.datapointid AND j29.columnname = 'fdrD3_Iang_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j20 ON DC.datapointid = j20.datapointid AND j20.columnname = 'fdrD3_Iang_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j31 ON DC.datapointid = j31.datapointid AND j31.columnname = 'fdrD3_Iang_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j32 ON DC.datapointid = j32.datapointid AND j32.columnname = 'fdrD3_Iang_N' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j33 ON DC.datapointid = j33.datapointid AND j33.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j34 ON DC.datapointid = j34.datapointid AND j34.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j35 ON DC.datapointid = j35.datapointid AND j35.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j36 ON DC.datapointid = j36.datapointid AND j36.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_A-B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j37 ON DC.datapointid = j37.datapointid AND j37.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_B-C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j38 ON DC.datapointid = j38.datapointid AND j38.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vang_C-A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j39 ON DC.datapointid = j39.datapointid AND j39.columnname = 'fdrD3_PF_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j40 ON DC.datapointid = j40.datapointid AND j40.columnname = 'fdrD3_PF_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j41 ON DC.datapointid = j41.datapointid AND j41.columnname = 'fdrD3_PF_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j42 ON DC.datapointid = j42.datapointid AND j42.columnname = 'fdrD3_PF' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j43 ON DC.datapointid = j43.datapointid AND j43.columnname = 'fdrD3_Pst_V_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j44 ON DC.datapointid = j44.datapointid AND j44.columnname = 'fdrD3_Pst_V_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j45 ON DC.datapointid = j45.datapointid AND j45.columnname = 'fdrD3_Pst_V_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j46 ON DC.datapointid = j46.datapointid AND j46.columnname = 'fdrD3_Plt_V_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j47 ON DC.datapointid = j47.datapointid AND j47.columnname = 'fdrD3_Plt_V_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j48 ON DC.datapointid = j48.datapointid AND j48.columnname = 'fdrD3_Plt_V_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j49 ON DC.datapointid = j49.datapointid AND j49.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vdev_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j50 ON DC.datapointid = j50.datapointid AND j50.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vdev_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j51 ON DC.datapointid = j51.datapointid AND j51.columnname = 'fdrD3_Vdev_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j52 ON DC.datapointid = j52.datapointid AND j52.columnname = 'fdrD3_Fdev' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j53 ON DC.datapointid = j53.datapointid AND j53.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_I_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j54 ON DC.datapointid = j54.datapointid AND j54.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_I_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j55 ON DC.datapointid = j55.datapointid AND j55.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_I_C' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j56 ON DC.datapointid = j56.datapointid AND j56.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_I_N' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j57 ON DC.datapointid = j57.datapointid AND j57.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_V_A' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j58 ON DC.datapointid = j58.datapointid AND j58.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_V_B' 
LEFT JOIN datelist j59 ON DC.datapointid = j59.datapointid AND j59.columnname = 'fdrD3_THD_V_C'
```

Comment: No it will not because the column names will always be different

Comment: @kevinc -- please see new query

Comment: the problem with this is that the Column names always change because the DataSharing Table allows user to specify what columns

Comment: @kevinc - That is easy when you build the query dynamically just read them from the table in the same way you did to make `listStr` in your original query

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the sub Query, I hope this would speed up the execution and not produce the incorrect result.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM   (SELECT [datapointdate], 
                   dp.columnname, 
                   [datapointvalue] 
            FROM   [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[vw_datacollection] DC 
                   JOIN [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing] dp 
                     ON DC.datapointid = DP.datapointid 
            WHERE  [datapointdate] >= 'Jul 15 2013 12:00AM' 
                   AND [datapointdate] < 'Jul 22 2013 12:00AM' 
                   AND dc.datapointid IN (SELECT [datapointid] 
                                  FROM   [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing] 
                                  WHERE  filename = 'fdrD3')) AS source
           PIVOT ( Sum(datapointvalue) 
                 FOR columnname IN (select distinct dp.columnname 
                             from [FCPP_HPSD].[dbo].[datasharing] dp ) AS pvt 
    ORDER  BY datapointdate 
    FOR xml path('DataRow'), root;
```

**EDIT**
may be the where clause would be needed if you want the selected data. it works in Oracle.
I put the sub query back in place and added another one in the Pivot, just to simplify the Code and to ensure any new data would also be catered in future.

Comment: This causes it to run even slower

Comment: this is hard to believe.. I have always observed that sub-queries are slower the joins and where clause. Please consider any network related issues.

Comment: Yes I am asking our network engineers to verify network issues

Comment: There is also the chance that the subquery and the join do NOT give the same result. (E.g. when there are multiple records with the same datapoint for given filename; not saying that this is the case here, but you can't be sure either)

Comment: @deroby in this case I can claim the result is correct because i have not even suggested the join. in cases like these, sub queries should be eliminated since they incur lot more cost in terms of time required. the where clause obviously reduces the tuple in the intermediate relations. In general, there is always a chance of writing up a wrong join or where clause :D

Comment: @Tauseef I have tried it and it takes the same amount of time as my query. I think issue might be due to Pivot being so slow

Comment: yes @kevinc it might be the case, sub queries may take the same time as where clause in cases where sub queries are trivial ones or the output tuple does not have many records. this is an interesting post. I shall study Pivots in detail ASAP. :)

Comment: @Tauseef you're right about the fact that eliminating sub-queries is a good idea, but your suggested code tries to connect the tables in a different way than the orignal. In fact, the code you suggest doesn't even work as the filename points to the wrong table. But even after fixing that you still get different results, see this [sqlfidlle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1507c/13) for an example situation where your code goes wrong.

Comment: @deroby May be Yes, you are right.. in the fact the dc.datapoint was being used to join the dc and dp. may be it can affect the results. What about using the subquery in Pivvot? is it legal? would it benefit?

Comment: @deroby Wow, yes, the join NOW is definitely wrong, I guess the code was updated in this part. I did make sure the tables are same and i spent almost a minute on that :P Thanks for pointing out. in oracle we can use inner query in pivot in".

Comment: Impressive if Oracle supports this, but sadly MSSQL does not (well, 2008 doesn't in each case). You need to list them 'manually', that's why the OP build a stored procedure around it that converts the query in `@listStr` and then merges everything into dynamic sql.

Comment: yes, tried it on fidle but did not work, hgave error.
For Oracle, this is the link http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php#pivot

Answer (score 0):

From the SqlFiddle I would suggest to put an extra index on DataSharing (FileName, DataPointID). However, from your comment it seems that the actual query only takes 6 seconds (is this including the time needed to send all 547k records to SSMS ?) so that leaves the remaining time sucked up by the PIVOT and conversion to XML ?

- Could you give a timing in how long it takes to just do the SELECT but then pumped INTO a temp-table ?
- Could you give a timing on how long it takes to just do the PIVOT from said temp-table INTO another temp-table ?
- Could you give a timing on how long it takes to do the conversion to xml from the last temp-table when stored into a variable ?

Code wise I'm not a fan of sub-queries either, but it seems safer to use a WHERE EXISTS() construction than an outright JOIN imho. Then again, the optimizer often realises this too and already does this under the hood for us. Thus the query-plan of below probably looks identical to the original one.

```
Select * 
  From ( SELECT [DatapointDate]
                ,dp.ColumnName
                ,[DataPointValue]
           FROM [DataCollection] DC
           JOIN [Datasharing] dp
             ON DC.DataPointID = DP.DatapointID
          WHERE [DatapointDate] >= 'Jul 15 2013 12:00AM'
            AND [DatapointDate] < 'Jul 22 2013 12:00AM'
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                           FROM [DataSharing] ds 
                          WHERE ds.[FileName] = 'fdrD3' 
                            AND dc.DataPointID = ds.[DatapointID])
       ) AS source
PIVOT
    (
        SUM(DataPointValue)
        FOR ColumnName IN ([fdrD3_kWh_A],[fdrD3_kWh_B],[fdrD3_kWh_C],[fdrD3_kWh],[fdrD3_I_A],[fdrD3_I_B],[fdrD3_I_C],[fdrD3_I_N],[fdrD3_V_A],[fdrD3_V_B],[fdrD3_V_C],[fdrD3_V_A-B],[fdrD3_V_B-C],[fdrD3_kV_C-A],[fdrD3_kW],[fdrD3_kVA],[fdrD3_kVAr],[fdrD3_kW_A],[fdrD3_kW_B],[fdrD3_kW_C],[fdrD3_kVA_A],[fdrD3_kVA_B],[fdrD3_kVA_C],[fdrD3_kVAr_A],[fdrD3_kVAr_B],[fdrD3_kVAr_C],[fdrD3_F],[fdrD3_Iang_A],[fdrD3_Iang_B],[fdrD3_Iang_C],[fdrD3_Iang_N],[fdrD3_Vang_A],[fdrD3_Vang_B],[fdrD3_Vang_C],[fdrD3_Vang_A-B],[fdrD3_Vang_B-C],[fdrD3_Vang_C-A],[fdrD3_PF_A],[fdrD3_PF_B],[fdrD3_PF_C],[fdrD3_PF],[fdrD3_Pst_V_A],[fdrD3_Pst_V_B],[fdrD3_Pst_V_C],[fdrD3_Plt_V_A],[fdrD3_Plt_V_B],[fdrD3_Plt_V_C],[fdrD3_Vdev_A],[fdrD3_Vdev_B],[fdrD3_Vdev_C],[fdrD3_Fdev],[fdrD3_THD_I_A],[fdrD3_THD_I_B],[fdrD3_THD_I_C],[fdrD3_THD_I_N],[fdrD3_THD_V_A],[fdrD3_THD_V_B],[fdrD3_THD_V_C])
    ) as pvt

ORDER BY DatapointDate
FOR XML Path('DataRow'), ROOT
```

One more question: do you really need the `ORDER BY DatapointDate` there ?